# JPQL and Enum. If you need any Enum

Tags: enums, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL query that includes several filters and sorting at once.

```
    @Query("SELECT rest FROM Restaurant rest LEFT JOIN rest.votes vote " +
            "WHERE (rest.name LIKE concat('%', :searchQuery, '%') OR rest.address LIKE concat('%', :searchQuery, '%')) " +
            "AND rest.cuisine = :cuisine " +
            "GROUP BY rest.id ORDER BY COUNT(vote.id) DESC")
    Page<Restaurant> findAllSortedByRating(@Param("searchQuery") String searchQuery, 
                                           @Param("cuisine") СuisineType cuisine, 
                                           Pageable pageable);
}
```

In the third query line, :cuisine is an Enum. Everything works fine when the user has selected one of the options, but what if he wants to see all the options.

For example, with searchQuery, I simply pass an empty string and get the entire list. Of course, this is not possible with Enum, but maybe there is a way to implement such functionality?

So far, I just made two methods in one of which there is no this line, but this is not beautiful because the code is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `is null`

```
AND (rest.cuisine = :cuisine or :cuisine is null)
```

Or you could add `СuisineType.ALL`

```
AND (rest.cuisine = :cuisine or :cuisine = com.demo.СuisineType.ALL)
```

Comment: Thanks, my code is much smaller and cleaner

Comment: @ИгорьМешалкин If an answer solves your problem, please accept that answer so that it can be closed, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.